# Pagination not showing current page in DataGrid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I have implemeted fuelux data grid successfully however the grid is not showing the current page(as shown below).

[image]

There are no JavaScript errors, i have included the all.js file of the fuelUX but still doesn't seem to be working.

Is there anything obvious that i may be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your code somewhere? I think at one point, we did have an issue with the styling of the datagrid - it definitely looks like the size of the select is incorrect, so it could be that it's not initializing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known condition when using the datagrid inside `.row-fluid`.  Please see the GitHub issue below for a workaround, discussion, and tracking any improvements that are made for this.

https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/141